# Docker pass containerID to the application running inside container itself

Tags: docker

How can I pass containerID to a java application as JVM parameter running inside same container itself.

```
containerıd is stored in /etc/hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to read the `HOSTNAME` environment variable inside the container. That happens to be the ID of the container.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.0-rc3, build 4d92237

$ docker exec -it dddca22b89a4 bash
root@dddca22b89a4:/# env
HOSTNAME=dddca22b89a4
...
...
```

(I am using Docker for Mac, BTW)

Comment: root@febris01:/home/bipdev/ahmetk/pnsender/docker]# docker exec  715510c7f710 echo $HOSTNAME
febris01

Comment: as you can see that  HOSTNAME is nt containerID

Comment: It seems PS1 is

Comment: what is that? PS1

Comment: The command is incorrect. I verified and updated my answer. Try `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` and then try `echo $HOSTNAME` inside the container shell.

Comment: PS1 is an environment variable, your default prompt, here it is `the_user@the_container_id`

Comment: In a docker file ı have assinged as its, but HOSTNAME return null,   ENV JAVA_OPTS="-DCONFIG_HOME=. -DLOGDIR2=logs/${HOSTNAME}"   ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]

Comment: docker exec ded98fecfc41 env   ,,,  JAVA_OPTS=-DCONFIG_HOME=. -DLOGDIR2=logs/